# change the default message error of parsley.js "This value seems to be invalid"

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

How can i change the custom message error of parsley.js "This value seems to be invalid" after the user inputs wrong data, im using data-parsley-pattern that only allows letter and not special characters or numbers.

```
<label for="l_name">Last name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input name="l_name" id="l_name" type="text" class="form-control" required="" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]+$">
```

Im just new to web, i tried to understand the docs but my knowledge seems not enough to fully grasp it.

i tried data-parsley-`constraint`-message="my message" and
data-parsley-error-message="my message" but nothing happened. Thanks

Comment: Try the `adderror()` method http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the custom validators:

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="l_name">Last name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input name="l_name" id="l_name" type="text" class="form-control my-field" required=""  data-parsley-lastname>
    <input type="submit"></submit>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name=myForm]").parsley();
window.Parsley.addValidator('lastname', {
  validateString: function(value) {
    var patt = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$");
    return patt.test(value);
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'My message'
  }
});
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/ZrvwEq

Comment: Hi can you provide a js fiddle for this? i tried it but the "This value seems to be valid" is still appearing instead of the custom error

Comment: @SallyMcsalad: updated the response and the codepen link to have a custom validator

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the documentation, you can customize any error message with, for example `data-parsley-pattern-message="..."`, or for all error messages `data-parsley-error-message="..."`

Comment: `data-parsley-pattern-message="..."` did the job! Thanks!